# How can I open my default webbrowser in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2013

I am trying to create a custom command called WebBrowser which will open my default webbrowser and go to google.com when I click on it.  So far I only made the exit command, and I a really stuck how to implement this command.  Any help would be amazing.

The XAML is:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfTutorialSamples.Commands.CustomCommandSample"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:self="clr-namespace:WpfTutorialSamples.Commands"
    Title="CustomCommandSample" Height="150" Width="200">
<Window.CommandBindings>
    <CommandBinding Command="self:CustomCommands.Exit" CanExecute="ExitCommand_CanExecute" Executed="ExitCommand_Executed" />
</Window.CommandBindings>
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Menu>
        <MenuItem Header="My Command">
            <MenuItem Command="self:CustomCommands.Exit" />               
        </MenuItem>
    </Menu>
    <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
</Grid>
</Window>
```

The code-behind is:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace WpfTutorialSamples.Commands
{
public partial class CustomCommandSample : Window
{
    public CustomCommandSample()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void ExitCommand_CanExecute(object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        e.CanExecute = true;
    }

    private void ExitCommand_Executed(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Application.Current.Shutdown();
    }
  }

  public static class CustomCommands
  {
    public static readonly RoutedUICommand Exit = new RoutedUICommand
            (
                    "Exit",
                    "Exit",
                    typeof(CustomCommands),
                    new InputGestureCollection()
                            {
                                    new KeyGesture(Key.F4, ModifierKeys.Alt)
                            }
            );
  }
  }
```

I am trying to make it look like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/k8ezB.png

Comment: `Process.Start(url)` ?

Comment: I read that online but where do I put it?  Custom commands are so confusing to me.

Comment: In your command `Execute` method

Comment: I don't get it?  Sorry, I am still trying to learn all of this and it doesn't make any sense to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a command which starts a new process and gives it as an argument a URL. I am using [DelegateCommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff654132.aspx) here but you can use any custom ICommand you already have:

```
public DelegateCommand StartChromeCommand = new DelegateCommand(OnStartChrome);

private void OnStartChrome()
{
   var process = new Process(new ProcessStartInfo {Arguments = @"http://www.google.com"});
   process.Start();
}
```

Comment: OP asked default browser. `Process.Start(url)` is just fine

Comment: I must be dumb, sorry.  I have to dumb it down even further?  Where would I put that code inside my code?  Everywhere I tried I kept getting errors?

Comment: If this is just an exercise, you can put it in your CustomCommandSample class.

Comment: Yea, its just an exercise, I am trying to figure out custom commands, but I still don't get it very well.